# jQuery.Deferred exception Error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

In this code I get this error. i have tried to look it up online but i dont seem to get any answers.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/test/comment_insert.js:44:24)
at l (http://localhost/test/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
at c (http://localhost/test/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677)
```

What have I done wrong?

```
.then(function(data) {
    comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
    console.log("ResponseText: " + data);
});
```

Edit 2 : i have provided the full code. i still do not understand how to fix this problem. i am still new to coding. maybe by providing the full code you guys may be able to see what i am trying to do.

```html
$( document ).ready( function(){
 
 //this will fire when the page is fully loaded
 
 $( '#comment-post-btn' ).click( function(){
  comment_post_btn_click();
 
 });
 
 
});



function comment_post_btn_click(){
 
 //records the text within the textarea 
  var _comment = $( '#comment-post-text').val();
  var _userId = $( '#userId').val();
  var _userName = $( '#userName').val();
  
  
  if( _comment.length > 0 && _userId != null){
   
   //proceed with our ajax callback
 $('.comment-insert-container').css('border' , '1px solid #e1e1e1');
      
      
 $.post("comment_insert.php" ,
 {
      
 task : "comment_insert",
 userId : _userId,
 comment : _comment 
 } 
 )
 .catch(function()
 {
 console.log("Error: " );
 })
     
 .then(function(data)
 {
 comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
 console.log("ResponseText: " + data);
  }); 
      
      
 console.log(_comment + " Username: " + _userName + " User Id:" + _userId);
  }
  else{
   // displays message when textarea is empty
   $('.comment-insert-container').css('border' , '1px solid #ff0000');
   console.log("The text area was empty");
  }
  
  
  //this line of code clears the text area when button is clicked
  $( '#comment-post-text').val("");
 
 
}



function comment_insert(data){
 
 
 var t = '';
 t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_'+data.comment_id+'">';
    t += '<div class="user-img">';
 t += '<img src="'+data.profile_img+'" class="user-img-pic"/>';
 t += '</div>';
 t += '<div class="comment-body">';
 t += '<h3 class="username-field">'+data.userName+'</h3>';
 t += '<div class="comment-text">n'+data.comment+'</div>';
 t += '</div>';
 t += '</div>'; 
 t += '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
 t += '<ul>';
 t += '<li class="delete-btn">X</li>';
 t += '</ul>';
 t += '</div>';
 t += '</li>';
 
 
 $('.comments-holder-ul').prepend( t );
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=Unexpected+token+<+in+JSON) before posting, and say specifically what previous answers you've tried and why they didn't work. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Clearly, `data` doesn't contain JSON. It's either a string starting with `<` (most likely an error message in HTML), or it's an object that, when `String(...)` is called on it, returns a string starting with `<`.

Comment: So how would i fix it. im still new to this type of coding, can you provide an example for me?

Comment: @fehmiE first, check what is actually inside your `data`, you can use `console.log(data)` to log the content in your browser console. Depending on that, you might need to fix the source if the JSON

Comment: i have added the full code maybe this may help into finding the problem.

Comment: we still don't know what's inside `data` when it comes from your server. Can't tell that just by looking at Javascript code. You need to find out by looking in your browser's dev tools

Comment: But basically whatever is coming back, it's not JSON. Probably it's HTML. Check what the server is sending you. Post the code of comment_insert.php here if you don't know how to fix it to return the correctly formatted data.